# Reversing domain 'sharding' with htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Previously I've been using domain sharding to serve images from a cookieless domain. I've changed all the paths from domain.com/wp-content/uploads/* to /media/ with the following htaccess-rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://media.domain.com/$1
```

This resulted in the following link:

```
https://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image.jpeg
```

To be redirected to:

```
https://media.domain.com/2017/08/image.jpeg
```

Yesterday I made my switch to HTTP/2, which makes 'domain sharding' not necesary. So this time around, I want to do the oposite switch, switching from media.domain.com to domain.com/wp-content/uploads. I've tried this by placing the following in the htaccess-file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads$1
```

However, this results in an infinite loop:

```
https://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/image.jpeg
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: It is good to know that 'media' is a subdomain that is placed in the 'public_html' directory of the main website. So public_html is the main website and public_html/media is the media folder. The htaccess is placed in public_html

Comment: "...to /media/ with the following htaccess-rule:" - The redirect is mostly superfluous (unless you specifically had a lot of images indexed by search engines or linked to directly by third parties?!). Unless you had physically changed the image URL to `media.example.com` in your application then you won't have benefited from "domain sharding" - in fact, if this was only implemented with a redirect (which you seem to imply) then this would have been bad for users, your server (and potentially SEO)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by placing the htaccess with the rule in the media-folder, instead of public_html. Silly me. :)